# (IntelliJ IDEA) "invalid Python interpreter selected for the module"

Tags: python, intellij-idea, sdk, interpreter

I'm a fairly new programmer, and I've been following courses and stuff to learn Python.

I am used to developing small projects using IntelliJ IDEA and Python 3.6, but recently I tried downloading Anaconda and its modules so I could try some Machine Learning courses. (I can use all of Anaconda's modules (Spyder, Jupyter Notebook, Anaconda Prompt,...)

But for some reason, that installation seem to have messed up with my IntelliJ IDEA configuration, the main problem being that it can't find a proper interpreter or SDK for some reason.

I've been to JetBrains Help page, but I can't seem to get it working, my understanding about IDE's, interpreters, SDK and all that being quite limited...

Is there a problem of compatibility between Anaconda and that particular IDE? 
Is there an easy way to find and set correctly the interpreter and/or SDK??

For your time, thank you

Comment: Files ---> Settings. Then select project interpreter and give your python path. You can give path of your old python executable or you can give anaconda's python path.

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ docs about how to [Change module SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.1/sdk.html#module_sdk).

> 1. From the main menu, select File | Project Structure (⌘;).
> 2. Under the Project Settings section, select Modules.
> 3. Select the necessary module and click Dependencies.
> 4. From the Module SDK list, select another SDK or SDK version you want
>      to use.

Answer (score 1):

No compatibility issue. Go to

> `file->settings-> project: my project-> project interpreter`

. On the right hand side, press the "gear" icon, select "add local" and choose the specific version of python installation location,navigate to  `python.exe` on your computer.

OR

```
'file-> Settings-> Project_interpreter->
 click "gear" icon-> Press ADD
```

create virtual environment in particular empty folder.setup your base Interpreter with python.exe(python in linux).Import all global packages.Press OK.